# Ignoring/commenting classes and packages in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm doing some major refactoring on an `Android` app on `Android Studio`. This involves copying, refactoring and testing `classes` to a new project.

While doing these work, some `classes` and `packages` are broken and will remain this way until I refactor them. These `packages` and `classes` are still not used by any other `classes` in my project.

I want to test the work I have done on the `classes` that are already refactored without having to erase the code that is already imported.

Is there a way to tell `Android Studio` to ignore these broken `classes/packages` and build the code into an `apk` without having to remove or comment them all manually?